# Raspberry pi не присваивается ip-адрес для ethernet

Tags: linux, raspbian

Недавно начал пользоваться малиной, до этого опыта с линуксом не было.
Через некоторое время малине перестал присваиваться айпишник для проводного соединения, но при этом для wifi все работает идеально:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:75:d2:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dece:cb2d:57e7:fe57  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:20:87:d9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16736  bytes 10435974 (9.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7945  bytes 1085900 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Если кто-то сталкивался или что-то может подсказать, помогите пжл

Comment: Проверить кабель. Линк есть на порту свитча? Индикаторы горят?

Comment: RUNNING = линк, линка нет)